# How can I write a powershell script which runs as one user, but prompts for a login with encrypted passwords?

Tags: powershell, encryption, script, passwords, login

To describe the **use-case**: I'm in the process of writing a powershell script for automation on a local machine, which multiple users have access too. I'd like the script to do specific things depending on which user is currently on the machine.

requirements:

1. only one windows user
2. users have to execute the script manually

I know about **get-credentials** and saving that in a file. But I'm still new to powershell and very uncreative when it comes to storing multiple passwords (like **5-10**) and checking them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about one or multiple users. like multiple humans can access the PC but all login with the same user? anyway about passwords this article is one of my favorites: https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/ read part one and part two.

Comment: to clarify, multiple humans log in with multiple accounts

Comment: if you only need to do stuff depending on the user, without the need of credentials, then the parameter `$env:username` already contains your desired info